# "#" contained in string as parameter of macro for string replacement

Tags: xstring

How to handle the "#" that is part of the string parameter for a macro def?
How to replace "#" from that parameter with another charater(s)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\notesus}[1]{
\StrSubstitute{#1}{s}{ sustained}
        }

\newcommand{\notesharp}[1]{
    \noexpandarg
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{\#}{ sustained}
}


\begin{document}

    The songs is mostly written in \notesus{Cs} \par 
    Not many songs combine the simultaneous use of flats and sustained notes
    particularly \notesus{Fs}\par 
    But most of the time we use C\# to denote C sustained  
    I need to use C# without back slash betwen C and # like this \notesharp{C#} 



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a better replacement facility; here a trailing `s` or `#` is changed in the contents of `\c_hpcolos_sustained_tl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\notes}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_hpcolos_notes_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { [s\#] \Z } { \u{c_hpcolos_sustained_tl} } \l_hpcolos_notes_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_hpcolos_notes_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l_hpcolos_notes_tl
\tl_const:Nn \c_hpcolos_sustained_tl { ~ sustained }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verb|Cs|: \notes{Cs}

\verb|Fs|: \notes{Fs}

\verb|C#|: \notes{C#}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place this immediately after `\begin{document}`:

```
\catcode`\#=12
```

Then, the hash is just an ordinary character in your document body. Works, as long as you are not creating macros in the body.